# Shared library not containing symbol for included method?

Tags: linux, build, cmake, makefile, shared-libraries

I cannot show code (as its proprietary). I have a file invoking the method of a class defined elsewhere, so I include the header for that class. My IDE intellisense can determine where the method is located. However, after compiling and installing the binaries, when I run the app it crashes citing the symbol missing for a method from the aforementioned class.

I checked the library symbols (using nm) and the one I require is missing.

My question is, considering I have included the header, what other possible things could explain why the symbol is missing? If there was an identical method signature from another header, would both (rather than none) be listed in the shared library?

Could the problem be with cmake that its not linking the second header? How could I check this?

Answer (score 1):

> considering I have included the header, what other possible things could explain why the symbol is missing?

Including the header is *never* sufficient to get a symbol; you *must* also link in the object file (or library) for the other class.

> Could the problem be with cmake that its not linking the second header?

You are confused: headers do not play any role in linking at all, only object files and libraries do.

A possible source of your confusion: Microsoft compilers support magical `#pragma comment(lib, "foo")`. If you `#include` a header with such `pragma` in it, and then give your object to the linker, it will conveniently and automagically append `foo.lib` to your link line.

UNIX linkers usually do not have such "black magic", and the whole feature is considered to be a *mis*-feature by some.